# how to log googleplus votes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-plus-one

i am trying to log googleplus votes. Once the user clicks on googleplus I want to fire a callback and alert a message. I got:

js

```
function plusone_vote(obj) {
        alert('logged'); //this alert does not come up:(
    }

html:

  <g:plusone size="medium" count="false" href="www.mysite.com"></g:plusone>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<g:plusone size="medium" count="false" href="www.mysite.com" callback="plusone_vote"></g:plusone>
```

You can use the `callback` attribute. Actually the [Google +1 button generator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) does provide this options.

Comment: hi Derek, just tried this still does not work? Is it working on your machine?